# How can I change the language of packages from other distros?

Tags: apt, gnome, 22.04, language-support, cinnamon

I installed some programs from other distributions, such as [gnome-disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) (Ubuntu/Gnome) or [mintstick](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintstick) (Linux Mint/Cinnamon) on my Kubuntu (Ubuntu/KDE) system.

Unfortunately, they couldn't adapt their (default english) language to global system language (which is not english).

Gnome-based apps seems to change their default language to system language by installing necessary language packs:

```
$ sudo apt install language-pack-gnome-<your language>
```

However I couldn't find any similar packages (or solutions) for Mint/Cinnamon-based programs.

Comment: Disks is not from another distro. It's available in the Ubuntu archive together with the packages which are installed by default in Kubuntu. As regards mintstick i don't know. Did you install any translation files together with the program?

Comment: I see that also mintstick has been packaged for Debian and is with that available in the Ubuntu archive as from Ubuntu 22.10. Try to install it [from there](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/all/mintstick/download), and you will get translations too.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem.